# DataFlowJavaOperator - execute specific java class file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I am new to GCP Composer. Trying to schedule my job via Airflow.

I have single JAR which contains batchjob1.java, batchjob2.java, I am using DataFlowJavaOperator for scheduling.

Refer below code for reference.

```py
DataFlowJavaOperator(
        task_id='batchjob1',
        jar='gs://bucket/path/jobs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
        options={
        }
    )
```

Here, how can i make call to batchjob1.java and batchjob2.java specifically. Is there any way to specify Mainclass in DataFlowJavaOperator

Comment: I think you should file this as a feature request against Airflow. It makes sense. Your idea is simple and normal. Forcing the user to make a self-executable jar seems needless. It might be simpler for them to share one jar.

Comment: @KennKnowles : found one option, which worked for me. posted as answer for reference.

Comment: Ah, I just totally missed that. It is perfect. I am going to delete my answer, since it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring through documentation, found one option which worked for me.

Just specify your class name in **job_class**

```
dataflow_task = DataFlowJavaOperator(
    task_id='example1',
        jar='gs://bukcet/path/job.jar',
        job_class='package.jobClassName',
        options={
            
        },
    dag=dag)
```